# Oracle Group by issue

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below query.  The problem is the last column productdesc is returning two records and the query fails because of distinct. Now i need to add one more column in  where clause of  the select query so that it returns one record. The issue is that the column i need
to add should not be a part of group by clause.

```
  SELECT product_billing_id,
         billing_ele,
         SUM(round(summary_net_amt_excl_gst/100)) gross,
         (SELECT DISTINCT description 
            FROM RES.tariff_nt 
           WHERE product_billing_id = aa.product_billing_id 
             AND billing_ele = aa.billing_ele) productdescr
    FROM bil.bill_sum aa
   WHERE file_id = 38613 --1=1
     AND line_type = 'D'
     AND (product_billing_id, billing_ele) IN (SELECT DISTINCT 
                                                    product_billing_id, 
                                                    billing_ele 
                                               FROM bil.bill_l2 )
     AND trans_type_desc <> 'Change'
GROUP BY product_billing_id, billing_ele
```

I want to modify the select statement to the below way by adding a new filter to the where clause so that it returns one record .

```
(SELECT DISTINCT description 
   FROM RRES.tariff_nt 
  WHERE product_billing_id = aa.product_billing_id 
    AND billing_ele = aa.billing_ele
    AND (rate_structure_start_date <= TO_DATE(aa.p_effective_date,'yyyymmdd') 
    AND rate_structure_end_date > TO_DATE(aa.p_effective_date,'yyyymmdd'))
) productdescr
```

The `aa.p_effective_date` should not be a part of `GROUP BY` clause.  How can I do it?  Oracle is the Database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So there are multiple RES.tariff records for a given product_billing_id/billing_ele, differentiated by the start/end dates

You want the description for the record that encompasses the 'p_effective_date' from bil.bill_sum. The kicker is that you can't (or don't want to) include that in the group by. That suggests you've got multiple rows in bil.bill_sum with different effective dates.

The issue is what do you want to happen if you are summarising up those multiple rows with different dates. Which of those dates do you want to use as the one to get the description.

If it doesn't matter, simply use MIN(aa.p_effective_date), or MAX.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is the Oracle analytical functions only way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into the Oracle analytical functions. This is good link [Analytical Functions by Example](http://www.orafaq.com/node/55)

Comment: -1 because analytic functions are rarely helpful when aggregating rows and this answer will not help the original poster.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Is the Oracle analytical functions only way to solve this issue?